# Decrypting Lua Bytecode Error

Tags: lua

When I try to decrypt this bytecode:

```
local crypt = '27\76\117\97\83\0\25\147\13\10\26\10\4\8\4\8\8\120\86\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\40\119\64\1\255\201\207\1\0\0\0\0\0\108\105\110\101\108\101\110\103\116\104\32\61\32\49\48\48\48\32\45\45\72\111\119\32\108\111\110\103\32\121\111\117\32\119\97\110\116\32\101\97\99\104\32\108\105\110\101\32\111\102\32\111\98\102\117\115\99\97\116\101\100\32\99\104\97\114\97\99\116\101\114\115\32\116\111\32\98\101\46\13\10\45\45\73\102\32\116\104\101\32\115\99\114\105\112\116\32\105\115\32\116\111\111\32\108\111\110\103\32\119\104\101\114\101\32\116\104\101\32\111\117\116\112\117\116\32\115\97\121\115\32\34\109\101\115\115\97\103\101\115\32\100\105\115\99\97\114\100\101\100\34\32\116\104\101\110\32\99\104\97\110\103\101\32\116\104\101\32\110\117\109\98\101\114\32\116\111\32\52\48\48\32\111\114\32\49\48\48\48\44\32\101\116\99\46\13\10\97\32\61\32\115\116\114\105\110\103\46\100\117\109\112\40\102\117\110\99\116\105\111\110\40\41\13\10\13\10\108\111\99\97\108\32\99\111\100\101\32\61\32\39\92\50\55\92\55\54\92\49\ 49\55\92\57\55\92\56\49\92\48\92\49\92\52\92\52\92\52\92\56\92\48\92\48\92\48\92\48\92\48\92\48\92\48\92\48\92\48\92\48\92\48\92\48\92\48\92\48\92\48\92\50\92\53\92\54\49\92\49\92\48\92\48\92\53\92\54\52\92\48\92\48\92\50\56\92\49\50\56\92\49\50\56\92\48\92\54\92\49\50\56\92\54\52\92\48\92\55\92\48\92\48\92\48\92\53\92\49\57\50\92\48\92\48\92\54\92\48\92\54\53\92\48\92\54\92\54\52\92\54\53\92\48\92\57\92\49\57\50\92\54\53\92\49\51\49\92\53\92\49\57\50\92\48\92\48\92\54\92\48\92\54\54\92\48\92\54\57\92\49\57\50\92\48\92\48\92\55\48\92\49\50\56\92\49\57\52\92\48\92\55\48\92\54\52\92\49\57\52\92\48\92\57\92\54\52\92\49\50\56\92\49\51\50\92\53\92\49\57\50\92\48\92\48\92\54\92\49\57\50\92\54\54\92\48\92\54\57\92\49\57\50\92\48\92\48\92\55\48\92\48\92\49\57\53\92\48\92\55\48\92\54\52\92\49\57\52\92\48\92\57\'
```

I get the following error: "unfinished string near 27LuaS". How can I fix this?

Comment: Replace a single \ with \\.

Comment: Did you get that error when you ran that code with the full string or only that snippet?

Answer (score 1):

- Add one \ at the beginning of the string
- Remove the \ at the end of the string
- Remove a line break in the middle of the string

The program then runs. If you write that string to a file, then you'll get truncated Lua 5.3 bytecode. It seems that your original script is incomplete.

Comment: But How Can I find the middle of the string?. Yes I Only Posted The Half of the string because the original string is 1 million long.

Comment: @Night If you didn't post the full string, then lhf's answer was misguided. You should state in your question that you didn't post the full string.